# p content vertical HTML5 and overlay

Tags: javascript, html

Some method to achieve this?. From what I've seen is necessary to use javascript but still do not see how.

[image]

code: http://codepen.io/gcpmendez/pen/mEmzPa

html:

```
 <div class="languages-list" style=" padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <span >L<sub>1</sub> </span>
        <p class="form-control"> </p>
        <button  id="alphabet-language-1">Σ<sub>1</sub> </button>
    </div>`
```

css:

```
.languages-list p {
 width:300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius:100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  position:absolute; overflow:hidden;
  float:left; top:100px; left:100px;

  text-align: center;
}

.languages-list span {
    position:absolute; 
    float:left; top:80px; left:245px;
}
.languages-list button {
 width:70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius:100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  position:absolute; overflow:hidden;
      float:left; top:110px; left:320px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want https://jsfiddle.net/7ku7qvfx/13/

remove `text-align: center` then add `padding-left` instead.

```
.languages-list p {
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  padding-left: 140px;
  //text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @GermánMéndez what do you mean? What part needs work?

Comment: when the text overflows use "..." at the end. know?

Comment: @GermánMéndez Oh gotcha!, this will be fun to figure out.

Comment: @GermánMéndez can I use JQuery?

Comment: Yes. Have you seen anything interesting?

Comment: @GermánMéndez no, but I am almost done. ended up using pure javascript. Kinda funny.